# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument in subclass

Tags: python, class, scoping

I have values in a nested table. I need to do some calculations and get the results. The classes are organized in `script1.py` and `script2.py`.

There is the superclass `Values`, which reads each row in the list and converts them into numpy arrays.

There is also the subclass `Dimensions`, which inherits the arrays from `Values` and does the calculations.

The code operates with the table and gets the results, but doesn’t work. I get the error message:

> **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'tbl'

`script1.py`:

```
import numpy as np

class Values:
    def __init__(self, tbl):
        self.tbl = tbl

    def get_val_a(self):
        val_a = np.array(self.tbl[0])
        return val_a

    def get_val_b(self):
        val_b = np.array(self.tbl[1])
        return val_b

    def get_val_c(self):
        val_c = np.array(self.tbl[2])
        return val_c
```

`script2.py`:

```
from script1 import Values

val = Values()

class Dimensions(Values):

    def __init__(self, tbl):
        super().__init__(tbl)

    def get_dim_a(self):
        dim_a = 2 * val.get_val_a()
        return dim_a

    def get_dim_b(self):
        dim_b = 2 * val.get_val_b()
        return dim_b

    def get_dim_c(self):
        dim_c = 2 * val.get_val_c()
        return dim_c
```

`script3.py`:

```
from script2 import Dimensions

table = [[1, 2, 3],
         [1, 4, 9],
         [1, 8, 27]]

dim = Dimensions()

dim_1 = dim.get_dim_a()
dim_2 = dim.get_dim_b()
dim_3 = dim.get_dim_c()
print('Dimensions: ', dim_1, dim_2, dim_3)
```

Comment: Well, you are not passing in an argument when you call `Dimensions()` but `Dimensions.__init__()` clearly expects a `tbl` argument. Did you mean to call `Dimensions(table)` instead?

Comment: Why are you creating `val`  at the module level in `script2.py` anyway?  Not only is it unneeded (every method you call on it is already inherited by `Dimensions`), it ensures that every `Dimensions` object you create will contaminate the data of every other `Dimensions` object.

Comment: Come to think of it... How do these two classes help you do anything but slow down the numpy array you're already creating (over and over and...)?  Are you trying reflect changes made to `table` by some code outside these classes?

Comment: Thank you. The first I have to say is I’m not programmer, I’m structural (civil) engineer and my programming learn method is mainly trial and error and surfing the net.

Comment: The idea is what I call here ‘table’ in reality is a csv file with all the steel sections according to the American, European, etc., standards. This file contains the geometrical and other basic characteristics of each section.

Comment: I write a class, which read, filter and convert the basic values of the table to numpy arrays in order to use any of them in future calculations. In my question, script1 should be a simplified example.

Comment: In a second step, I operate with these arrays making different calculations in order to obtain the values for tension, compression, buckling, fatigue, bolt connections, etc. and following the recommendations of different standards (American, European and so on depending on the project). The checks can be hundreds and I will be working on the methods over years. My idea is to have a package with the classes and methods I’ll create over the time. Here, script2 should be another example.

Comment: Once I have done this previous work, I come to script3, where I have to solve a specific problem. Each time the problem can be a different one, such specific calculations for a bridge.

Comment: In short, I organize the three different steps (read from csv file, calculations according to standards, solve the specific problem) in different scripts/packages to prevent having all of them in a mega-huge script.

Comment: I’m going on and on, but so maybe you can understand better my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have these instantiation attempts in your code:

```
val = Values()
dim = Dimensions()
```

You need to pass the relevant arguments to them in order to instantiate, since the `__init__` method is called implicitly when you instantiate and it expects an argument in both cases.

Comment: Ok, but how can I do that since the argument is in a different script?

Comment: @PedroBiel:  According to the code you've posted, they're in the _same_ file (`script3.py`), so you'd pass your argument to the `Dimensions` initializer in the same way you'd pass it to any other callable.

Comment: If I write in script3
`dim = Dimensions(table)`
I get the same error message.
If I write in addition script2
`val = Values(table)`
I get the following error message:
`NameError: name ‘table’ is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

**Idos** already stated the reason for failure, which I will not repeat. Looking at your code, I **am guessing** that you need to pass in the table:

```
# script3.py
dim = Dimensions(table)
```

In *script2.py*, I don't know why you create a `Values` object there and I don't know what to guess.

Comment: Please, see my answers to Kevin J. Chase.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your answers, I have followed the clue of passing the arguments. I have also realize that my example code was too simple to understand my problem.
What I’m looking for is:

1. Read any csv file with any dimensions. These csv files should include the information about steel sections and could be different from each other.
2. Assign the values of the columns of the csv file to arrays I can operate with.
3. Do basic calculations using different standards depending on the project.
4. Use the basic calculations to solve a specific problem of the project. This script may be different for each problem. The others with the classes shall be save to re-use.

So far, that is my best solution:

```
# csv file: table.csv
# -------------------

#a,b,c
1,2,3
1,4,9
1,8,27

# script1
# -------

import numpy as np
import csv

class ImportFileCSV:
    '''
    Read any csv file and transpose the rows to columns.
    There are different csv files with different dimensions.
    '''

    def __init__(self, file_csv):
        self.table_csv = []
        self.file_csv = file_csv

    def read_table_csv(self):
        with open(self.file_csv, newline = '') as f_csv:
            reader = csv.reader(f_csv)
            for row in reader:
                if row[0].startswith('#'): continue # Ignore the header.
                self.table_csv.append(row)       
        self.table_arr = np.array(self.table_csv)
        return self.table_arr.T       

class Values(ImportFileCSV):
    '''
    Assign the values of each column to an array.
    There would be different classes Values1, Values2... for each csv file.
    '''

    def __init__(self, file_csv):
        super().__init__(file_csv)
        import_file_csv = ImportFileCSV(self.file_csv)
        self.table = import_file_csv.read_table_csv()

    def get_val_a(self):
        val_a = np.array(self.table[0], dtype = int)
        return val_a

    def get_val_b(self):
        val_b = np.array(self.table[1], dtype = int)
        return val_b

    def get_val_c(self):
        val_c = np.array(self.table[2], dtype = int)
        return val_c

# script2
# -------

from script1 import Values

class Dimensions(Values):
    '''
    Do some basic calculations according to specific standards.
    For each standard there would be different classes Dimensions1, Dimension2...
    '''

    def __init__(self, file_csv):
        super().__init__(file_csv)
        self.val = Values(self.file_csv)

    def get_dim_a(self):
        dim_a = self.val.get_val_a() + 2
        return dim_a

    def get_dim_b(self):
        dim_b = self.val.get_val_b() * 2
        return dim_b

    def get_dim_c(self):
        dim_c = self.val.get_val_c() ** 2
        return dim_c

# script 3
# --------

# PROJECT

from script2 import Dimensions

dim = Dimensions('table.csv')

dim_a = dim.get_dim_a()
dim_b = dim.get_dim_b()
dim_c = dim.get_dim_c()

solution = dim_c - dim_a - dim_b

print('Dimensions:', dim_a, dim_b, dim_c)
print('Solution  :', solution)

# Results
# -------

Dimensions: [3 3 3] [ 4  8 16] [  9  81 729]
Solution  : [  2  70 710]
```